# String API Data changing into object

Tags: reactjs

I got the data from open source api, and I am trying to to get the data one by one from the list. However, when I display data from render parts, it shows in a string type just like example below. My question is should I change this to object and make it into a list and get the data one by one? Or did I something do wrong from my code. My code is too many

dataartistListid5137nameCheat CodesticketLinkhttps://edmtrain.com/new-jersey?event=110880&ticketsfestivalIndnamedate2019-05-25venueid3250nameBorgata PremierlocationAtlantic City, NJaddress1 Borgata Way, Atlantic City, NJ 08401, USAstateNew Jerseylatitude39.378longitude-74.435agescreatedDate2019-03-20T23:15:05Zlinkhttps://edmtrain.com/new-jersey?event=110880id110880artistListid375nameLaidback LuketicketLinkhttps://edmtrain.com/new-jersey?event=111099&ticketsfestivalIndnamedate2019-05-25venueid5414nameHQ2 NightclublocationAtlantic City, NJaddress500 Boardwalk, Atlantic City, NJ 08401, USAstateNew Jerseylatitude39.363longitude-74.414ages21+createdDate2019-03-22T19:56:21Zlinkhttps://edmtrain.com/new-jersey?event=111099id111099artistListid83nameArmin Van BuurenticketLinkhttps://edmtrain.com/new-jersey?event=111373&ticketsfestivalIndnamedate2019-05-25venueid5415nameHQ2 BeachclublocationAtlantic City, NJaddress500 Boardwalk, Atlantic City, NJ 08401, USAstateNew Jerseylatitude39.363longitude-

```
// reducer
export default handleActions({
    ...pender({
        type: GET_POST_LIST,
        onSuccess: (state, action) => {
            const { data: posts } = action.payload;

            const lastPage = action.payload.headers['last-page'];
            return state.set('posts', fromJS(posts));
        }
    })
}, initialState)
```

```
    //Container
    render() {
            const { loading, posts, city, state } = this.props;

            if(loading) return null; // Do not show anything while loading
            return (
    <div>
    <PostList posts={posts}/>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }

    export default connect(
        (state) => ({
            //lastPage: state.list.get('lastPage'),
            posts: state.list.get('posts'),
            loading: state.pender.pending['list/GET_POST_LIST']
        }),
        (dispatch) => ({
            ListActions: bindActionCreators(listActions, dispatch)
        })
    )(ListContainer);
```

````
```
//PostList component
const PostList = ({posts}) => {
    const postList = posts;
    return (
        <div>
            {postList}
        </div>
    );
};

export default PostList;
````

Answer (score 0):

I realize that I used fromJS which changes all into array from reducer. Took out that part and I got data in an object type.